# EBS vs Instance Local storage for MongoDB in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb, amazon-ebs, cassandra

Cassandra recommends using instance local storage for EC2 deployments instead of EBS

I am deploying MongoDB in EC2... should I also be using instance local storage instead of EBS PIOPS?

Comment: That depends. The data on an instance-store drive is irrevocably destroyed when the instance is terminated. If you've got a replica set setup and good backups, the performance might be worth the risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mongo documentation on EC2](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) recommends using EBS over instance store:

> EC2 instances can be configured either with ephemeral storage or
>   persistent storage using the Elastic Block Store (EBS). Ephemeral
>   storage is lost when instances are terminated so it is generally not
>   recommended for use unless you’re comfortable with the data-loss
>   implications.
>
> For almost all deployments EBS will be the better choice. For
>   production systems we recommend using
>
> - EBS-optimized EC2 instances
> - Provisioned IOPS (PIOPS) EBS volumes

Comment: I wonder why though, because Mongo handles data loss at the app layer via replication.

Comment: @stevelandiss Because in the unlikely but possible situation that your instances all go down at the same time (region failure, perhaps) you'd lose everything despite replication.